# Using the aggregate with DBref and Mongo-ODM

Tags: mongodb, doctrine-odm

I am trying  to reproduce the following working query - from mongo console - using mongo-odm.

```
db.Record.aggregate([ {$match: {member: DBRef("Member", ObjectId("556e5dbfa10fdb0ddc0041c5"), "doctrine_odm")}}, {$sort: {timestamp: -1}}, {$group : {_id : "$details.type", firstRecord: {$first: "$_id"}}}  ])
```

A sample Record is

```
{

"_id" : ObjectId("556e5dbfa10fdb0ddc0041c8"),

"member" : DBRef("Member", ObjectId("556e5dbfa10fdb0ddc0041c5"), "doctrine_odm"),

"timestamp" : ISODate("2015-06-03T01:51:59Z"),

"details" : [

{

"accountNumber" : "101",

"type" : "premium"

}

]

}
```

I've tried several formats and the latest - still not working - is like this

```
$collection = $dm->getDocumentCollection('Record');
$pipeline = array(
array(
'$match' => array(
"member" => \MongoDBRef::create("Member", "556e5dbfa10fdb0ddc0041c5", "doctrine_odm")
)
),
);

$results = $collection->aggregate($pipeline);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the ID needs to be a MongoId, so if I use the format

```
$pipeline = array(
array(
'$match' => array(
"member" => \MongoDBRef::create("Member", new \MongoId("556e5dbfa10fdb0ddc0041c5"), "doctrine_odm")
)
),
);
```

It works.